# How do I test a that crouton message ALERT was displayed using espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, crouton

I am doing automated testing using espresso. Normally if i had a message displayed I would use the resource id to locate the TextView or an element i want to test.
Like this

```
 onView(withId(R.id.myTextViewID)).check(matches(withText(containsString("Message im checking"))));
```

Now the problem with crouton ALERT messages is i don't know which id to check against.

Comment: Are you referring to this library? https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
    onView(withText(containsString("Message you're checking"))).check(matches(anything()));
```

the `matches()` part already checks that the view exists in the view hierarchy. I think that's enough to check. You can replace the `anything()` with `isDisplayed()` if you want, but that check might fail if it's performed in the instant when the Crouton view has been added to the view hierarchy, but is not yet visible even partly.